# How to add custom Ads in my Android app and change them from a Web Site?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want to add custom ads in my android app i do not want to use services like admob and inmobi, i want to add my own ads and be able to change them from a web client.

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there and where?

Comment: Post what you have tried. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a question.

Comment: can i see what you have done till now ?

Answer (score 0):

Save your ads script code on server and use webservices to fetch these ads code..
use ads code where you want to use.. 
its simple budy

On server side you easily manage this code.